# Why is the length of a BAPS (binary almost perfect sequence) a multiple of 4?

Tags: sequences-and-series, correlation

a BAPS is a binary sequence of length $n$ with an almost perfect autocorrelation:
$$
A(\tau)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
n & \tau=0 \\ 
k & \tau= {n \over 2} \\ 
0 & else
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
for sequence of $\{ +1,-1\}^n$.

now, it is clear that $n$ is an even number, but why is $n\ mod\  4 = 0$?

Comment: What is $A(\tau)$?

Comment: it is the autocorrelation function: $$A(\tau)= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i a_{i+\tau}$$